# Save JSON objects' pairs in an array

Tags: php, json

I am very new to JSON and i really need help. So I have been given this $oldAuctions object and after using PHP's json_decode function (`json_decode($oldAuctions, TRUE);`) it returned me something like this that has 11 objects with 9 set of name/value pairs in each...

```
{
    "recent_results": [
        {
            "closing_yield": "0.800",
            "auction_id": "106",
            "use_buy_it": "0",
            "issuer": "National Bank",
            "term": "1 Year",
            "is_charity": "1",
            "end_date": "12-26-2012",
            "closing_price": "100.000000",
            "issue_type": "FDICs"
        },
        {
            "closing_yield": "1.090",
            "auction_id": "339",
            "use_buy_it": "0",
            "issuer": "National Bank",
            "term": "1 Year",
            "is_charity": "1",
            "end_date": "12-12-2012",
            "closing_price": "100.000000",
            "issue_type": "FDICs"
        },
        {
            "closing_yield": "2.000",
            "auction_id": "041",
            "use_buy_it": "0",
            "issuer": "National Bank",
            "term": "5 Year",
            "is_charity": "1",
            "end_date": "09-11-2012",
            "closing_price": "100.000000",
            "issue_type": "FDICs"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to grab each pair and save their values in an array. For example, I want to grab the `auction_id` and save it's values in an array.....how can I do that?

Also, just for simple testing purpose I tried to print out the values first...but that didn't work either...

```
foreach($oldAuctions as $IDs)       
{
   echo 'Ids: '.$IDs->auction_id;
}
```

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: What you posted looks like the JSON object _before_ decoding it, not what `json_decode()` returned.

Comment: Oh, and my PHP is NOT the 5.3 version. Thanks!

Comment: What does `$oldAuctions` contain? JSON string or Array?

Comment: @Barmar: oops, u r right. i actually used `json_encode`

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: i believe it's an array (what i posted in my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After invoking `json_encode` your array `$oldAuctions` has become a JSON **string**. You can not iterate through it as array or object as its a string.

As `$oldAuctions` is already an array you can simply use `forach`

```
foreach($oldAuctions['recent_results'] as $result){
    echo 'Ids: '.$result['auction_id']. "\n";
}
```

Comment: AH! i see :) Thank you! another silly question, how to save them in an array now?

Comment: `$new_auctions[] = $result['auction_id'];` will add the auction ID to the `$new_auctions` array.